# SuperSearch in multiple custom fields with just one checkbox

Tags: solspace, supersearch

So, I'm doing a filtration of my search results.
I'm using checkboxes.

In order to get the colours I need to filter with, I loop through all the entries and run it through stash to get rid of duplicates.
Then I put these values in a checkbox-input.

This works great when just looking in one custom field, but with 4 custom fields, not so much.

I can loop out everything as I'm supposed to, but the submitting value needs to be the name of the field it should search in. Meaning the name="farg[]" should be name="frg_2[]" and so on.

The colour "Yellow" can be in any/all of the customs fields, hence me having to run it through stash to get rid of duplicates.

Running supersearch 3.1.4 and EE 3.3.3.
Any suggestions?

Here's the code.

```
        {!-- Loops out all the colours and stores in list --}
            {exp:stash:set_list name="farger" trim="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
                {exp:channel:entries search:typ="keramik" channel="produkter"}
                    {if farg != ''}
                        {stash:farger}{farg}{/stash:farger}
                    {/if}
                    {if frg_2 != ''}
                        {stash:farger}{frg_2}{/stash:farger}
                    {/if}
                    {if frg_3 != ''}
                        {stash:farger}{frg_3}{/stash:farger}
                    {/if}
                    {if frg_multi != ''}
                        {stash:farger}{frg_multi}{/stash:farger}
                    {/if}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            {/exp:stash:set_list}

        {!-- Get list, loop out with color name, avoid duplicates --}
            <div class="filter-holder">
                <h6>Färg</h6>
                {exp:stash:get_list
                    name="farger"
                    orderby="screen_name"
                    sort="asc|desc"
                    sort_type="string|numeric"
                    unique="yes"
                    parse="start"
                }
                    <div class="filter-name">
                            <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="farg[]"
                            value="{farger}"
                            id="{farger}"
                            class="checkbox"
                            {if super_search_farg == '{farger}'}checked{/if}
                            />
                            <label for="{farger}"><span></span>{farger}</label>
                    </div>

                {/exp:stash:get_list}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
So, once again, I'll answer my own question.

Instead of having the colours in 4 different custom fields, I put them all in one grid, with 4 fields. That way, I can do a search in the grid, and not on a specific color-field.

Boom! Magic! :)
Hope this helps someone else too.